# Change Youtube user name

Tags: video, youtube

I have logged in using gmail for youtube. I have uploaded some videos from my account.

Now what should be done if want to change a name for youtube ?

I have changed google plus name which is connected to youtube. There it changes a name even it changes name when i go to profile in youtube. If I go to my profile it displays updated username that it "USERNAME uploaded a video". But if I search in youtube without logging into my account then it displays old name as uploader of the video.

I don't know why this happens ? I thought if we change a name in google+ it will automatically update it everywhere where ever we have used gmail account to login.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about the features of a third-party web site.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is not about programming

Answer (score 0, accepted):

WRT to search results, let Google update its search results, once done, you should be able to get the new name appearing in search results. Indexing and updating results takes a bit of a time.

I was reading https://support.google.com/youtube/answer/2657964 and in the end it says:
`Note that it may take some time for the changes to update throughout the site.`

I guess all you need to do is wait for sometime.

Comment: but link you posted is for channel's name not for account's.

Comment: Hi.. Sorry I missed out on your comment.. Was your issue resolved or still facing any probs?